# How to disable validating empty fields with bootstrapvalidator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using following validation in my web page. If I keep this field as empty and press submit, it shows the green correct icon as this field is valid. Is there a way to avoid this in BootstrapValidator? I mean if field is empty don't show that green icon.

```js
                    contactNumber: {
                        validators: {
                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^[+|0-9][0-9]*$/,
                                message: '.........'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 10,
                                max: 15,
                                message: '.......'
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using 'error.form.bv' event. Inside this event handler we can remove unnecessary validations on empty fields.

```
$('#someForm').bootstrapValidator({

// some code

}).on('error.form.bv', function(e) {
            if($('#someClass') && $('#someClass').val().length == 0 && $('#someClass').parents('.form-group').hasClass('has-success')){
                $('#someClass').parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
                $('#someClass').parents('.form-group').find('.form-control-feedback[data-bv-icon-for="someClass"]').hide();
            }

}).on('success.form.bv', function (e) {

// some code

});
```